# When Spring RestTemplate throws org.springframework.web.client.HttpStatusCodeException

Tags: java, spring-rest

org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate method exchance(..) throws RestClientException which is parent of org.springframework.web.client.HttpStatusCodeException, what are the possible scenario when restTeamplte.exchange(...) could throw this exception?

I checked the javadoc and tried to search it on internet but no luck.

```java
try {
final ResponseEntity<String> response = applicationApiTemplate.exchange(uri,
                    HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
} catch(HttpStatusCodeException e) {
// when possibly i will get this error?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exhange(...) method of `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` class was added in `3.1.0.RELEASE` of spring-web library.

This method throws `RestClientException` which covers client (4_xx) and server (5_xx) side http code errors. But `RestClientException` doesn't offer `getStatusCode(), getResponseAsString()`, etc... methods.

1. `HttpsStatusCodeException` is the child of `RestClientException`  which is doing same thing but with additional methods like `getStatusCode(), getResponseAsString()`, etc.
2. `HttpClientErrorException` child of `HttpsStatusCodeException` and only entertain client error (4_xx) not the server error.
3. `HttpServerErrorException` child of `HttpsStatusCodeException` and only entertain server error (5_xx) not the client error